# Dynamically Import XML files to HIVE

Tags: xml, hive, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform

How to create HIVE table from XML file , with only few specific fields?? 
For example I have a XML file of 1000 fields but I need only 100 fields in my HIVE table. And apart from that. How do I store the 100 fields in different databases and different tables?

Answer (score 0):

The usual method is to run XLST transformations on your XML file and produce 1 to N csv files that can you store on HDFS, then expose data through HIVE external tables, or load to ORC/Parquet tables in a second stage.

Comment: Is there anyway I can expose directly to HIVE , without performing XLST transformations?

Comment: yes, using HIVE xpath; See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375031/exploding-a-row-of-xml-data-in-hive

Comment: Thanks Harold. I think that helps