# project array to columns in hive

Tags: hive

Is it possible to project an array into separate columns in hive in one step?

I have this query

```
select split(activity_data,":") as ad from log_table
```

where the column ad contains 10 separate fields which I would like to project into 10 columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible. I know there are two ways to do this:

1. Use indices to access array elements:

   select split(activity_data,":")[0] as col1, split(activity_data,":")[1] as col2 ... from mpod_audit_log
2. explained on this post. [Explode the Array of Struct in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373543/explode-the-array-of-struct-in-hive)

Comment: for simple situations this works, but if we do not know how many columns will be present I'm not sure how this can be used.

Answer (score 3):

I did it this way: By directly using array indexes to create separate columns in `Hive`:

sample `table` columns `datatype`: tbl_name(eid `bigint`, `array`<`double`> `as` spendings)

```
select eid, spendings[0] as spendings_1, spendings[1] as spendings_2...
from tbl_name;
```