# Parse json undetermined number of nested with hive

Tags: json, hive

I want to parse a JSON with Hive.

I know the usual functions for parsing a JSON, but the problem is the structure of the JSON.
It has an indeterminate number of `tracks.features` maybe 2, maybe 10, maybe 100 and I need to take the coordinates field.

Is it possible to do this on Hive?

This is the JSON:

```
{
    "track":{
        "features":[
            {
                "geometry":{
                    "coordinates":[
                        -3.7175826,
                        40.4342724997222
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "geometry":{
                    "coordinates":[
                        -3.7170288,
                        40.4324255
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explode the Array of Struct in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373543/explode-the-array-of-struct-in-hive)

Answer (score 0):

```
with your_data as(
select '{
    "track":{
        "features":[
            {
                "geometry":{
                    "coordinates":[
                        -3.7175826,
                        40.4342724997222
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "geometry":{
                    "coordinates":[
                        -3.7170288,
                        40.4324255
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}' as json
)

select get_json_object(json, '$.track.features[0].geometry.coordinates[1]') as latitude1 from your_data d
```

Returns:

```
OK
40.4342724997222
```

Time taken: 0.058 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)