# Searching specific word occurrence in document using hive

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hiveql

Hi I have a document uploaded to a Hive table named `Data` with sample lines like below:

```
He is a good boy and but his brother is a bad boy.
He is a naughty boy.
```

The table's schema is:

```
create table Data(
    document_data STRING)
row format delimited
fields terminated by '\n'
stored as textfile;
```

I want to write a query that counts the occurrences of just the words `boy` and naughty` and outputs them as such:

```
 boy 3
 naughty 1
```

Comment: can we have the structure of your hive table?

Comment: create table Data(document_data STRING ) row format delimited fields terminated by '\n' stored as textfile;

Answer (score 0):

Here we will make use of the `LATERAL` capability which enables a single row to be transformed into several.

```
SELECT
    word,
    COUNT(*)
FROM Data
WHERE
    word="boy" OR
    word="naughty"
LATERAL VIEW 
    explode(split(document_data, ' ')) lateralTable AS word GROUP BY word;
```

I adapted a version that I found at [Word Count program in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039949/word-count-program-in-hive).